# React Native Expo - No Splash Screen Showing (White Screen)

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo, splash-screen

Im running an expo managed react native project and I can't figure this out for the life of me. When I first initialized Expo I had the typical splash screen show, but now, I can't see my splash screen at all it just shows a blank white screen (No errors either). Everything else works perfectly in terms of post splash loading, but i really need help getting the splash to show.

**What I've Tried:**

- Running on iOS simulator, iOS device, Android simulator (Same thing)
- Remove node_modules and package-lock.json and run 'npm i'
- Cleared cache for both Expo and npm
- Replaced app.js return statement with just <View><Text>...</Text></View> and still nothing.

Here's my setup:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "placeholder",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "placeholder",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "type:check": "npx tsc",
    "format:check": "prettier --check \"src/**/*\"",
    "format:write": "prettier --write \"src/**/*\"",
    "lint:check": "eslint \"App.tsx\" \"src/**/*\"",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix \"App.tsx\" \"src/**/*\"",
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.11",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.7.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.4",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "expo": "~46.0.6",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~4.3.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@redux-devtools/core": "^3.13.1",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.14",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.69.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.24",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
    "@types/styled-components-react-native": "^5.1.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.33.1",
    "eslint": "^8.22.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^22.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.2.4",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

**app.json**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "placeholder",
    "slug": "placeholder",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#1D1A1F"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "requireFullScreen": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#1D1A1F"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/images/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

**babel.config**

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true)
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin']
  }
}
```

**app.tsx**

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import Constants from 'expo-constants'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font'
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen'
import * as ScreenOrientation from 'expo-screen-orientation'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components/native'
import store from './src/redux/store'
import { lightTheme, darkTheme } from './src/res/theme/theme'
import Loading from './src/screens/loading/loading'
import { logger } from './src/logger/logger'
import Application from './src/components/application/application'

// Function to keep the splash screen visible while we fetch resources
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync()
  .then((data) => logger.log(`SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync() succeeded: ${data.toString()}`))
  .catch(logger.warn)

logger.log('NODE_ENV: ', Constants?.manifest?.extra?.env) //eslint-disable-line

export const App = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    SedgwickAveDisplay: require('./assets/fonts/sedgwick-ave-display/SedgwickAveDisplay-Regular.ttf'),
    QuicksandRegular: require('./assets/fonts/Quicksand/static/Quicksand-Regular.ttf'),
    QuicksandSemiBold: require('./assets/fonts/Quicksand/static/Quicksand-SemiBold.ttf'),
    QuicksandBold: require('./assets/fonts/Quicksand/static/Quicksand-Bold.ttf')
  })
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light')
  const selectedTheme = theme === 'dark' ? darkTheme : lightTheme

  // Load the app here
  useEffect(() => {
    // Hide splash screen after 2 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      SplashScreen.hideAsync()
        .then((data) => logger.log(`SplashScreen.hideAsync() succeeded: ${data.toString()}`))
        .catch(logger.warn)
    }, 2000)

    ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.PORTRAIT_UP)
      .then(() => {
        logger.log('ScreenOrientation.lockAsync() succeeded')

        return AsyncStorage.getItem('@theme')
      })
      .then((data) => {
        if (data) setTheme(data)

        setLoading(false)
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        logger.warn(e)
        setLoading(false)
      })
  }, [])

  if (loading || !fontsLoaded) {
    return <Loading />
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={selectedTheme}>
          <Application />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </Provider>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  )
}

export default App
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: For Anyone looking at this and finding no solution, I found it! If you are newer to Expo, you may not have been familiar with the fact that you can have multiple configuration files: `app.json` `app.config.js` `app.config.ts`. If you want to dynamically set configs or env variables, then don't use **app.json** and just use **app.config.js**. Or if using TS, use both **app.config.ts** and **app.config.js**: [link](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/configuration/#configuration-resolution-rules) AND [link](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/typescript/#appconfigjs)

Happy coding!

Comment: I have a similar issue with my code where I am loading fonts too in the App.tsx file. I have an app.json and an app.config.js file. But my custom splash screen is not showing up and just a white screen shows. Can you tell me what you did to solve your issue?

Comment: @user882290 I didn't realize that app.json and app.config.* accomplish the same things, so you'll find that you're overwriting one by using the other. Just use one of the files you mentioned above and it should work. At least thats what happened to me. **Personally i kept the app.config.* file and got rid of the app.json file

Comment: @mprouve you can use both files. Just spread the config of app.json into app.config.js to avoid overwriting. It works fine.